# How to connect MacBook Air to HDTV

Tags: hdtv, macbook-air

Which cable(s) should I buy to connect the latest MacBook Air (with Thunderbolt port) to an HDTV? I need it to carry audio as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H1824ZM/A/Moshi_Mini_DisplayPort_to_HDMI_Adapter?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY) is available from Apple.

You will also need an HDMI cable. Apple offers [this one](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC838ZM/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY) (as well as several others).